# Error en Login al hacer la petición con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Hola buenas tardes tengo una página que subí a internet, la página se muestra bien, pero el problema que tengo es que el login no funciona.

> Modal (formulario login)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
            <!-- sample modal content -->
            <div id="mymodal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="modal fade custom-modal modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content po-relative">
                        <div class="modal-body p-0 text-center">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-5 modal-bg-img" style="background-image: url('<?=base_url()?>assets/images/modal/iniciar_sesion.jpg');">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7">
                                    <div class="modal-bg">
                                        <img style="width:200%; max-width:200px;" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/logos/abacom.png" alt="wrapkit">
                                        <h2 class="font-light text-muted m-t-20 text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
                                        <form class="m-t-30" id="form_login">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12" id="alert">
                                                    <!-- Alerta -->
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input id="txt_usuario" name="txt_usuario" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Usuario">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input id="txt_password" name="txt_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                                    <button type="button" onclick="crear_sesion();" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-gradiant btn-arrow"><span>Entrar<i class="ti-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center m-t-40">
                                                    ¿No tienes una cuenta? <a href="#" class="text-danger">Registrarse</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="btn_cerrar">×</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
</div>
```

> Modal llama a funcion crear_sesion de JavaScript

```
function crear_sesion(){

            $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_controller/crear_session')?>',
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#form_login').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    //window.location.replace('<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_controller/inicio')?>');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    var html = '';

                        html += '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="ti-user"></i> Usuario / Contrase単a incorrecta.'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>'+
                                '</div>';

                    $('#alert').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
```

> JavaScrip llama a esta funcion del mi controlador admin_controller (para efector practicos retorno un TRUE)

```
public function crear_session(){

  echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

Lo que está pasando es que entra al error cuando yo le estoy retornando un TRUE.

Comment: Intenta poner el Datatype : "json" en minuscula y base_url que hace? Verifica esa url

Comment: No es eso ya lo hice

Comment: para salir de dudas, saca por pantalla el resultado de <?php echo base_url('index.php/admin_controller/crear_session')?>  y pégalo en el navegador, seguro que, como mínimo no tiene cabeceras json y es muy posible que algo mas antes de tu echo json_encode(...)

Comment: ya lo saque y lo pegue directamente en la url y tampoco jalo

Comment: y si pego la liga en el navegador me manda un 404

Comment: eso quiere decir que estas generando mal la url, no estas llamando a admin_controller así que nadie devuelve TRUE. no uses base_url() y ponla toda a mano a ver si te funciona. Hasta que no te funcione en un navegador no vale la pena probar el ajax.

Comment: tambien lo que cheque es que cuando pongo la url en el navegador me manda 404 pero como la pagina tiene SSL me muestra el sello de seguridad.